# How to utilize all cores with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have been fiddling with Python's `multiprocessing` functionality for upwards of an hour now, trying to parallelize a rather complex graph traversal function using `multiprocessing.Process` and `multiprocessing.Manager`:

```
import networkx as nx
import csv
import time 
from operator import itemgetter
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

cutoff = 1

exclusionlist = ["cpd:C00024"]

DG = nx.read_gml("KeggComplete.gml", relabel=True)

for exclusion in exclusionlist:
    DG.remove_node(exclusion)

# checks if 'memorizedPaths exists, and if not, creates it
fn = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                  'memorizedPaths' + str(cutoff+1))
if not os.path.exists(fn):
    os.makedirs(fn)

manager = mp.Manager()
memorizedPaths = manager.dict()
filepaths = manager.dict()
degreelist = sorted(DG.degree_iter(),
                    key=itemgetter(1),
                    reverse=True)

def _all_simple_paths_graph(item, DG, cutoff, memorizedPaths, filepaths):
    source = item[0]
    uniqueTreePaths = []

    if cutoff < 1:
        return

    visited = [source]
    stack = [iter(DG[source])]

    while stack:
        children = stack[-1]
        child = next(children, None)

        if child is None:
            stack.pop()
            visited.pop()
        elif child in memorizedPaths:
            for path in memorizedPaths[child]:
                newPath = (tuple(visited) + tuple(path))
                if (len(newPath) <= cutoff) and
                    (len(set(visited) & set(path)) == 0):
                    uniqueTreePaths.append(newPath)
            continue
        elif len(visited) < cutoff:
            if child not in visited:
                visited.append(child)
                stack.append(iter(DG[child]))

                if visited not in uniqueTreePaths:
                    uniqueTreePaths.append(tuple(visited))
        else: # len(visited) == cutoff:
            if (visited not in uniqueTreePaths) and
                (child not in visited):
                uniqueTreePaths.append(tuple(visited + [child]))
            stack.pop()
            visited.pop()
    # writes the absolute path of the node path file into the hash table
    filepaths[source] = str(fn) + "/" + str(source) + "path.txt"
    with open (filepaths[source], "wb") as csvfile2:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile2, delimiter=" ", quotechar="|")
        for path in uniqueTreePaths:
            writer.writerow(path)

    memorizedPaths[source] = uniqueTreePaths

############################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.clock()

    for item in degreelist:
        test = mp.Process(target=_all_simple_paths_graph,
                          args=(DG, cutoff, item, memorizedPaths, filepaths))
        test.start()
        test.join()

end = time.clock()
print (end-start)
```

Currently - though luck and magic - it works (sort of). My problem is I'm only using 12 of my 24 cores.

Can someone explain why this might be the case? Perhaps my code isn't the best multiprocessing solution, or is it a feature of my architecture *Intel Xeon CPU E5-2640 @ 2.50GHz x18 running on Ubuntu 13.04 x64*?

**EDIT:**

I managed to get:

```
p = mp.Pool()
for item in degreelist:
    p.apply_async(_all_simple_paths_graph,
                  args=(DG, cutoff, item, memorizedPaths, filepaths))
p.close()
p.join()
```

Working, however, it's **VERY SLOW**! So I assume I'm using the wrong function for the job. hopefully it helps clarify exactly what I'm trying to accomplish!

EDIT2: `.map` attempt:

```
partialfunc = partial(_all_simple_paths_graph,
                      DG=DG,
                      cutoff=cutoff,
                      memorizedPaths=memorizedPaths,
                      filepaths=filepaths)
p = mp.Pool()
for item in processList:
    processVar = p.map(partialfunc, xrange(len(processList)))   
p.close()
p.join()
```

Works, is slower than singlecore. Time to optimize!

Comment: Looks peculiar that you're waiting for each new Process to end (`test.join()`) before the loop goes around to start another Process.  Try starting at least 24 Processes before joining any of 'em.

Comment: Yeah, I was just adding functions to see what works... :D Is there a way to just as many processes as processors on the computer? (i.e. is there a system variable for cpus?) 

Also; if I start 24 processes, will they continuously add more nodes when they empty? I have 4700 nodes to sort! 

I'm assuming no, it seems like wishful thinking. Is there a way to do such a thing?

Comment: in a similar vein to `R`'s `mclapply`?

Comment: You may also want to consider [Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Too much piling up here to address in comments, so, where `mp` is `multiprocessing`:

`mp.cpu_count()` should return the number of processors.  But test it.  Some platforms are funky, and this info isn't always easy to get.  Python does the best it can.

If you start 24 processes, they'll do exactly what you tell them to do ;-)  Looks like `mp.Pool()` would be most convenient for you.  You pass the number of processes you want to create to its constructor.  `mp.Pool(processes=None)` will use `mp.cpu_count()` for the number of processors.

Then you can use, for example, `.imap_unordered(...)` on your `Pool` instance to spread your `degreelist` across processes.  Or maybe some other `Pool` method would work better for you - experiment.

If you can't bash the problem into `Pool`'s view of the world, you could instead create an `mp.Queue` to create a work queue, `.put()`'ing nodes (or slices of nodes, to reduce overhead) to work on in the main program, and write the workers to `.get()` work items off that queue.  Ask if you need examples.  Note that you need to put sentinel values (one per process) on the queue, after all the "real" work items, so that worker processes can test for the sentinel to know when they're done.

FYI, I like queues because they're more explicit.  Many others like `Pool`s better because they're more magical ;-)

### Pool Example

Here's an executable prototype for you.  This shows one way to use `imap_unordered` with `Pool` and `chunksize` that doesn't require changing any function signatures.  Of course you'll have to plug in your real code ;-)  Note that the `init_worker` approach allows passing "most of" the arguments only once per processor, not once for every item in your `degreeslist`.  Cutting the amount of inter-process communication can be crucial for speed.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def init_worker(mps, fps, cut):
    global memorizedPaths, filepaths, cutoff
    global DG

    print "process initializing", mp.current_process()
    memorizedPaths, filepaths, cutoff = mps, fps, cut
    DG = 1##nx.read_gml("KeggComplete.gml", relabel = True)

def work(item):
    _all_simple_paths_graph(DG, cutoff, item, memorizedPaths, filepaths)

def _all_simple_paths_graph(DG, cutoff, item, memorizedPaths, filepaths):
    pass # print "doing " + str(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = mp.Manager()
    memorizedPaths = m.dict()
    filepaths = m.dict()
    cutoff = 1 ##
    # use all available CPUs
    p = mp.Pool(initializer=init_worker, initargs=(memorizedPaths,
                                                   filepaths,
                                                   cutoff))
    degreelist = range(100000) ##
    for _ in p.imap_unordered(work, degreelist, chunksize=500):
        pass
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I strongly advise running this exactly as-is, so you can see that it's blazing fast.  Then add things to it a bit a time, to see how that affects the time.  For example, just adding

```
   memorizedPaths[item] = item
```

to `_all_simple_paths_graph()` slows it down enormously.  Why?  Because the dict gets bigger and bigger with each addition, and this process-safe dict has to be synchronized (under the covers) among all the processes.  The unit of synchronization is "the entire dict" - there's no internal structure the mp machinery can exploit to do incremental updates to the shared dict.

If you can't afford this expense, then you can't use a `Manager.dict()` for this.  Opportunities for cleverness abound ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm working through it now. Pool doesn't _seem_ viable, because I've got 5 arguments and I'm not sure how to make it take multiple arguments (I'm using pypy which is Python 2.7.3 so no `starmap`, and I'm not sure how to get `partial` working with that many arguments! Would you be able to add an example either for a `.map` with many arguments, or a `.Queue()` example?

Comment: Added a multiprocessing snippet that I've got working, but is far slower than single core running time.

Comment: Multiple args are no problem:  pass a (one) tuple.  The tuple can contain as many arguments as you like.

Comment: Hmmm, I can't for the life of me get it to work, could you provide a tuple example of the map function? I just want to clarify the syntax, and work out if the problem is elsewhere!

Comment: No time right now, but "of course" you need to change the **called** function too, to accept a single tuple argument instead of n different args.  For example, if the function **was** `def f(a, b, c)`, change to `def (t)` and add `a, b, c = t` as its first line.  Is that enough?

Comment: Not to spoil anything ;-), but I'm trying to nudge you toward one of the "map"-like functions with a `chunksize` argument.  That will slash the overheads.

Comment: Do you mean like EDIT2? I've been playing with `p.map` for an hour or so now, and in conjunction with `partial` have managed to figure out the arguments. Although it's not working, so I could still be very wrong!

Comment: Changed EDIT2 because I got it working, why I was trying to pass it strings I don't know - long day - but it's still slow, time to research chunks I suppose! Thank you for all your help. Your name shall forever been commented into my code!

Comment: See the edit to my answer - there are simpler ways to proceed ;-)  Good luck!

Comment: The question is should you use all the cores or not?