# How to make Python's multiprocess spawn to make use all the available CPUs

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing

I have an AWS instance has 32 CPUS:

```
ubuntu@ip-122-00-18-114:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep processor  | wc -l
32
```

My question is how can I make use of Python's [**multiprocessing**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) 
so that each command runs on every CPU.

For example with the following code, will each command run on every single CPU available?

```
import multiprocessing
import os
POOL_SIZE = 32
cmdlist = []
for param in items:
    cmd = """./cool_command %s""" % (param)
    cmdlist.append(cmd)
p = multiprocessing.Pool(POOL_SIZE)
p.map(os.system, cmdlist)
```

If not, what's the right way to do it?

And what happened if I set POOL_SIZE > # Processors (CPUs)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to utilize all cores with python multiprocessing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086106/how-to-utilize-all-cores-with-python-multiprocessing)

Answer (score 4):

First a little correction on your wording. A CPU has different cores and each cores has hyperthreads. Each hyperthread is the logical unit which runs a processor. On Amazon you have 32 vCPUs which correspond to hyperthreads, not CPUs or cores. This is not important for this question but just in case if you do any further research it is important to have the wording right. I'll refer to this "lowest logical processing unit" of hyperthread as vCPU below

If you do not specify the pool size:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
p.map(os.system, cmdlist)
```

then python will find out the number of available logical processors (in your case 32 vCPUs) itself (via `os.cpu_count()`).

In normal circumstances, all 32 processes run on separate vCPUs because Linux tries to balance the load evenly between them.
If, however there are other heavy processes running at the same time, then two processes might run on the same vCPU.

The key to understand here is how the Linux scheduler works: It periodically reschedules processes so all processing units are utilized about the same. That means if you start only 16 processes then they will spread out to all 32 vCPUs and utilize them about the same (use `htop` to see how the load spreads).

> And what happened if I set POOL_SIZE > # Processors (CPUs)?

If you start more processes than the available vCPUs, then a few processes need to share a vCPU. That means that they a process is periodically switched out in the context switch by the scheduler. If your process is CPU bound (utilized 100% cpu, e.g. when you do number crunching) then having more processes than vCPUs will slow down the overall process as you'll have the context switches which slow down and if you have communication between the processes (not in your example, but something you'd normally do when doing multiprocessing) which slow down as well.

However. If your processes are not CPU bound but e.g. disk bound (need to wait for the disk for read/write) or network bound (e.g. wait for the other server to answer) then they are switched out by the scheduler to make room for another process since they need to wait anyway.

Comment: And what happened if I set POOL_SIZE > # Processors (CPUs)?

Comment: @neversaint: I answered your additional question in my answer itself and also added some words about wording at the start

Answer (score 0):

Easy question is "Not exactly". You may get cpu count with `os.cpu_count()` function and run this number of processes. But only operating system assigns process to the CPU. And more than that - it might switch it to another cpu in some time. I won't explain how [preemptive multitasking](https://www.google.com/search?q=preemptive+multitasking&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) works here.

If you have other "heavy" processes running on this server - for example database or even web server - they might need some cpu time for their execution as well.

Some good news are that there is a thing named [Process Affinity](http://www.glennklockwood.com/hpc-howtos/process-affinity.html) exists that could be of use for your needs. But it is a kind of fine tuning the os.