# How to use all cores rather than threads in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Can you help me figure out the best way to handle the below.

I want to multi process so I am executing as many queries on the DB as possible, in the shortest possible time.  I've used multiprocessing dummy, I think this uses threads though? I can't seem to figure out how to use all cores, rather than just all threads?

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

dates_to_extract = ['ff', 'fff']

def do_process(s):
    #####SOURCE
    try:
        #source table conn
        engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://kieran:cccer@localhost/ran",echo = True)
        iconn = engine.connect()
    except:
        print('connection failure to source')

    ######DEST
    try:
        #dest table conn
        enginedest = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://kieran:cccer@localhost/ran",echo = True)
        iconndest = enginedest.connect()
    except:
        print('connection failure to destination')


    print(s)
    #data from source table
    try:  
        data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM ran.order_data', iconn)
    except Exception as e: 
        print('extract: ' + str(e))
          
    #data into destination table
    try:
        data.to_sql(name='tbjd', con=iconndest, if_exists = 'append')
    except Exception as e:
        print('insert: ' + str(e))

if __name__=="__main__":
    p=mp.Pool(cpu_count())
    p.map(do_process, dates_to_extract) 
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: The answer to this question seems to explain it well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086106/how-to-utilize-all-cores-with-python-multiprocessing

Comment: You are correct https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy _"multiprocessing.dummy replicates the API of multiprocessing but is no more than a wrapper around the threading module."_ so the answer would be: don't use that, use the real multiprocessing `import multiprocessing as mp`