# How to utilize all cores with python multiprocessing with concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm writing a simple script to do some preprocessing for an image dataset which involves resizing and adding filters.

Here is my code:

```
def preprocessing(tar_ratio, img_paths, label_paths, 
                  save_dir="output", resampling_mode=None):
    # with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for img_path, label_path in zip(img_paths, label_paths):
            src_ratio = get_ratio(label_path)
            if src_ratio is not np.nan:
                executor.submit(
                    process_single(src_ratio, tar_ratio, img_path, label_path, 
                                   save_dir=save_dir, resampling_mode=resampling_mode)
                )
            else:
                pass
```

I think it's more CPU bound, so `multiprocessing` is more suitable than `multithreading`. But after trying both of them, neither is working as expected where only two CPU cores are used.

I've read the following post, I wonder if there is a newer version of it using `concurrent.futures`?
[How to utilize all cores with python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086106/how-to-utilize-all-cores-with-python-multiprocessing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Executor.submit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) method accepts a callable as the first argument but you call the function, try this instead:

```
executor.submit(
    process_single,
    src_ratio,
    tar_ratio,
    img_path,
    label_path,
    save_dir=save_dir,
    resampling_mode=resampling_mode,
)
```

A simple example that illustrates a proper usage:

**test.py:**

```
import random
import time

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def worker(i):
    t = random.uniform(1, 5)
    print(f"START: {i} ({t:.2f}s)")
    time.sleep(t)
    print(f"END: {i}")
    return i * 2


def main():
    futures = []

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for i in range(5):
            futures.append(executor.submit(worker, i))

        print([f.result() for f in futures])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Example:**

```
$ python test.py
START: 0 (3.16s)
START: 1 (1.68s)
START: 2 (2.76s)
START: 3 (1.53s)
START: 4 (4.05s)
END: 3
END: 1
END: 2
END: 0
END: 4
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```